# I need help making my bot dm me not the author of the command

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have a main.js that already does the see what the command is so it knows im trying to do !report and is able to say text. I've also gotten it to dm the user who sent it - but not to dm me. (this is set up like the rest of my commands however those are just making the bot talk basically) The goal being it will tell me if someone needs help and I can just dm them to ask about what is going on. (I removed my ID and replace it with "My ID")

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const BluntSam = client.users.cache.get('My ID');

module.exports = {
    name: 'report',
    description: "Report a problem with this bot, channel, or people.",
    execute(message, args){
        if (message.toString().toLowerCase().includes('report')) {
            message.author.send('Your report request has been sent. Please wait for a response from <@My ID>.');
            message.author.send(message.author + ' has requested an assistance ticket.')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know i need to change --> "message.author.send(message.author + ' has requested an assistance ticket.')" but I just dont know how

Comment: You should read the documentation for the `Discord.Client`. That's why they wrote it. Downvoted because OP clearly did not do any research.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get your user. Use an async function or IIFE for this.
2. Message it.

```js
(async () => {
    let me = await client.users.fetch('YOUR-USER-ID');
    me.send('some message');
})();
```